# How to save string in varbinary database field using prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql

I was searching for a long time just to save a simple string in a varbinary(4096) in a MySQL database. There are some solutions, but none of them is working.

```
function addGCMRegistrationToken($username, $gcm_token) {
        //...

        $gcm_token_bin = (binary)$gcm_token;
        $gcm_token = unpack('H*', $gcm_token);
        $stmt->bind_param('bs', $gcm_token, $username);
        //...
    }
```

I somehow have to convert $gcm_token into a `varbinary`. Neither `binary()` nor `pack` yields a solution. The database field remains empty, though often no error occurs.

Can somebody please show me how to do the right conversion?

Comment: No. Its not binary. It's a string that was obtained by POST.

Comment: What is the reason for storing as binary? You can store anything, including a string as is, in varbinary. Why the need to do any conversion?

Comment: It's more efficient. I want to store a Google Cloud Messaging registration id which can be of length 4096. Furthermore I am curious about the solution ;)

Comment: Efficient in terms of space or processing? I am still not understanding the need for any conversion before inserting. Just store your value as you receive it.